# C++ lambda expression as an argument in function template

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I need to define a function that takes a set and a function as input to do the pretty printing of sets. For that matter I would like to explicitly specify the type of the function so that the compiler could recursive matching and thus the signature

```
template<typename T, PrettyPrinter>
std::string to_string(const std::set<T>& set, PrettyPrinter printer);
```

is not precise enough, as the compiler cannot infer the type of a function object needed. So instead, I would like to use explicit typing

```
template<typename T>
std::string PrettyPrinting::to_string(const std::set<T>& set, std::function<std::string(const T&)> printer){
    const char* separator = ", ";
    const char* leftDelimiter = "{";
    const char* rightDelimiter = "}" 

    std::string output = leftDelimiter;
    if(set.begin() == set.end()) return output + rightDelimiter;

    typename std::set<T>::const_iterator it = set.begin();
    output += printer(*it);
    for(++it; it != set.end(); it++) output.append(separator) += printer(*it);

    return output + rightDelimiter;
}
```

This does what I expect. However, I cannot use lamba expression in another template construction

```
std::string to_string(const std::set<std::string>& set){
    return to_string(set, [](const std::string& input){ return input; });
}
```

I get some weird error that lambda function is not appropriate argument. On the other hand, the following code works

```
inline std::string to_string(const std::set<std::string>& set){
   std::function<std::string(const std::string&)> printer = [](const std::string& input){ return input; };
   return to_string(set, printer);
}
```

Is there any rational reasons why does the compiler need an explicit function object? What should I specify as a type so that I could write lambda expressions directly as function arguments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to write a for\_each algorithm for MFC's CMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437404/trying-to-write-a-for-each-algorithm-for-mfcs-cmap)

Comment: Have you tried `return to_string<std::string>(...)` - i.e. bypass Template Argument Deduction? It's a lot shorter than your workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas and `std::function<...>` are two different types. [Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) does not care about implicit conversions. Try this:

```
template<typename T, typename PrintLambda, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<PrintLambda, std::function<std::string(const T&)> >::value >>
std::string PrettyPrinting::to_string(const std::set<T>& set, PrintLambda printer);
```

The above ensures that `PrintLambda` has the right signature by checking if it is convertible to the appropriate `std::function`.

Comment: Fair. Is this sufficient for compiler to instantiate `to_string` automatically for type `set<set<string>>` given only two template definitions specified above. This was the initial reason for explicit typing of the function object.  Also, what is the difference between my solution where the lambda is assigned to function object if I make the assignment static (so that ir would be initialised only in the first call of the function)?

Comment: @SvenLaur If your question is whether, after defining the body of this template function, the following will work `std::string to_string(const std::set<std::string>& set){
    return to_string(set, [](const std::string& input){ return input; });
}`, then yes it will.